# how to access a textfield in a group using apple script?

Tags: applescript

I am new to apple script and after several repeated attempts I found out that if i need to access a textbox in a window then i have to enter its group and found out i can check the tree using accessibility Inspector and here is my chain in the below screenshot, can anyone please tell me the line of script I should use to access the textfield

I have tried this code to do it and it is not working

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "myapp"
    -- set frontmost to true
    tell window 1
        tell group1
        exists text field
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Thanks in advance[image: UIElement Tree]

Comment: As the parent elements of the text field are `unknown` you might try `text field 1 of UI element 1 of UI element 1 of window 1`

Comment: `tell application "System Events" to tell process "MyApp"
  return name of text field 1 of UI element 1 of UI element 1 of window 1
end tell` something like this ?

Comment: That is not working for me, I am getting "System Events got an error: Can’t get text field 1 of UI element 1 of UI element 1 of window 1 of process \"MyApp\". Invalid index."

Comment: UI scripting is horrible. It's most of the time trial&error.

Comment: ya thats the saddest part lol

Comment: The UIElement position is changing dynamically, is there anyway to handle that ?

Comment: Yes, you could check if it contains an unique UI element for example a button with a particular title